# How to return an observabe based on the result of another observabe in angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Hi i am making a login page with angular 5. My method is following :

```
login(context: LoginContext): Observable<number> {
let profileId: number;

this.http.post<AuthRes>(SERVER_API_URL + "api/authenticate", context).subscribe(authRes => {
  profileId = authRes.profileId;
  this.tokenService.setToken(authRes.token, context.rememberMe);
});

return of(profileId);
}
```

My problem is sometimes, the profileId is returned as observable before that the first observable finish the work and i have an wrong result when I try to verfiy if the user is logged in or not.

I want to return the profileId only after the execution of my fisrt observable.

Thanks

Comment: Subscribe cant return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
login(context: LoginContext): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.post<AuthRes>(`${SERVER_API_URL}api/authenticate`, context)
         .do(authRes => this.tokenService.setToken(authRes.token, context.rememberMe))
         .map(authRes => authRes.profileId);
}
```

Comment: thanks it's work, I only needed to add this line to my imports : import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

Comment: NOTE: "do" not return an observable based on result of another observable, "do" only make a function when the observable is completed